# How would I create a simple log command for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I apologize if this question is something of the most simple, but I'm not even sure what terms I should use to search. What I'm trying to do is create a 'Sub' that will do something when I call it in another Sub, however I am unsure in how I would pass variables from one another. Here is what I have;

```
Private Sub Log
        LogBox.AppendText(logstuff & vbNewLine)
End Sub

Private Sub Log_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Log.Click
        Log("Some message here.")
End Sub
```

How would I make this work? The `logstuff` would be replaced with the log message, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax would be:

```
Private Sub Log( ByVal logstuff As String )
        LogBox.AppendText(logstuff & vbNewLine)
End Sub
```

`ByVal` specifies how the parameter will be passed into the function. Here it means "By Value". You can also pass something `ByRef` which means "By Reference". This should give you something to search for - you'll find lots of tutorials on parameter passing in VB, such as [this one](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets9p3.html).

Note that in most Editors, you can leave out the `ByVal` when you create the function.The editor will add it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a parameter to the sub. Maybe something like this :

```
  Private sub Log(byval logstuff as string) 
   ......
```